# Print from a list of values in Python 3

Tags: python, list

I have created this list of numbers

```
V = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
```

and after each iteration:

```
for j in range(len(V)):
```

I want to print a message with the number

```
print("error " + train_error + "of " + "{:.1f}".format(V[j]))
```

which returns an error. My aim is when I print a specific number from the list to be expressed in one decimal point (alternatively python returns 0 decimals).

This is the error I get: TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Comment: The info you give seems totally unrelated to the error you get, which you didn't even copy entirely...

Comment: @JulienBernu 

  File "<ipython-input-28-bb9dae6a77e8>", line 1, in <module>
    print("error " + train_error + "of {:.1f}".format(V[j]))

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will allow others to reproduce your error. The error you have indicates `numpy` is being used, but I don't see nay mention of it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do like this example:

```
V = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]

for k in V:
    # replace "train_error" with your variable
    print("error {0} of {1:.1f}".format("train_error",k))
    # Also you can do the same for train_error variable
    # print("error {0:.2f} of {1:.1f}".format(0.052400023937225342,k))
```

Output:

```
error train_error of 0.1
error train_error of 0.2
error train_error of 0.3
error train_error of 0.4
error train_error of 0.5
error train_error of 0.6
error train_error of 0.7
error train_error of 0.8
error train_error of 0.9
error train_error of 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the vague question but I am brand new to Python

Comment: Can I ask one more question please? What about if I want to do the same for the "train_error" variable? Do I replace {0} with {1:.1f} again? -- Apparently not :P I tried that

Comment: Yeah sure, is a float64, size 1, with the value: 0.052400023937225342

Comment: I upated my asnwer, check it.

Comment: Oh I see, I got it now. I think I know how it works! We always start with zero as the initial variable, then 1 for the second variable etc. Again, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> V = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
>>> for j in range(len(V)):
       print("{0:.1f}".format(V[j]))

0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

Is this what you are looking for?